# Variable not updating inside the view

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

For some reason, the variable Tags isnt being updated.  When SelectedSauce is ran, it should run the function and then update the variable.  But it's not being updated once it leaves the function.  Im not sure what is wrong with this. When I change views, I pass a variable to selectedsauce from the previous view to here.  im not sure if it helps or changes anything but I am using the Realm Database

```
class InfoUITableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var SelectedSauce: Sauce? {
        didSet {
            print("1st")
            AcquireData()
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("3rd")
        print("Loaded")

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DetailsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Super")
        tableView.dataSource = self

        //Returns nill even though i changed the variable in acquiredata
        print(Tags)
    }

    let realm = try! Realm()

    var Tags: List<NiceTags>?

    //MARK: - Data Manipulation

    func AcquireData() {
        print("2nd")
        if let Sauce = SelectedSauce {
            Tags = Sauce.tags
            //            print(Tags)
        }
            self.Tags = self.SelectedSauce?.tags
            print(self.Tags)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("4th")

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Super", for: indexPath) as! DetailsTableViewCell

        //This isn't running, and just uses the default text inside the label
        if let TheTags = Tags?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.Inflabel.text = TheTags.tags
        }


        return cell
    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of row
        print("5th")
        //Returns 7 because tags is still nill
        return Tags?.count ?? 7
    }
}
```

Comment: SelectedSauce has tags ? have you checked that ?

Comment: `lazy var Tags: List<NiceTags>? = List<NiceTags>()` try out this code as well ... initialise tags

Comment: Yeah its a custom created object / class I had created.  when I run the code and print self.tags in the function an array is printed out in the console

Comment: in acquireData it prints values ?

Comment: in acquireData you are setting it twice ...

Comment: I tried setting t twice because it wasn't working when I set it once for som reason.  Also the lazy var solution semi worked.  In the console its printing "Optional(List<NiceTags> <0x600000d96340> " but the cells when I load up the project don't display anything as before it would display 7 cells with "label" inside ( the default text inside the cell )

Comment: I have it print values so , that I know that it's not nil.  the purpose is to to assign new data to the variable tags

Comment: print new data first and after assign print tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214695/discussion-between-jawadali-and-calebtheperson).

Comment: Not related to your question, but Swift recommends that properties start with a lowerCase: `tags`, `selectedSauce`, etc.

Comment: Ik, but since im coding by myself, and just doing it for fun . I don't really care about stuff like that.  when I post here I try to refractor everything and make it neat for others.

Comment: If you use the accepted conventions, it is easier for others to read and hopefully get you a useful answer. And sorry, the code you posted is not neat at all.

Comment: meme, I know .  ive been working on this issue for awhile, haven't been able to go back and clean my stuff up lol

Comment: do you resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set SelectedSauce from tabbar like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad() 
swipeAnimatedTransitioning?.animationType = SwipeAnimationType.sideBySide 
// isCyclingEnabled = true 
// Do any additional setup after loading the view. 
print("order") 
let first_vc = self.viewControllers?.first as! DetailViewController 
let last_vc = self.viewControllers?.last as! InfoUITableViewController 
first_vc.SelectedSauce = SelectedSauce 
last_vc.SelectedSauce = SelectedSauce 
}
```